# AirflowException python_callable param must be callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am getting error in Composer DAG while passing parameters to composer DAG.

> AirflowException python_callable  param must be callable

These parameters will be used in other python script (py_script.py)  located in other directory.

Composer DAG:

```
default_dag_args = {    
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 01, 01),
    'catchup': False,
    'retries': 0,    
}

with models.DAG(
        'test',
        schedule_interval='None',
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
   
    t1 = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='t1_task',
        python_callable=py_script,  
        op_kwargs ={'PARAM1':'TEST',              
        'FILE':'gs://bucket/file.xlsx'},
         dag=dag
    )   

    t1
```

Python script in other folder:  /dir/folder/py_script.py

```
def main(**kwargs):

    PARAM1 = kwargs.get("PARAM1")
    FILE = kwargs.get("FILE")   
    
    
    print('PARAM1:', PARAM1)
    print('FILE:', FILE)
    
    #other process
```

Comment: python_callable must be a function.

Comment: `python_callable=py_script.main`

Answer (score 0):

inspectorg4dget said it - make sure you have `python_callable=py_script.main`